# matlab run script file from GUI push button

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

i have a  script file , want to run it from gui push button
its not working .

---

the  error is :

```
Undefined variable "classifyDeeb" or class "classifyDeeb.m".

Error in Train>pushbutton2_Callback (line 113)
classifyDeeb.m
Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Train (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)Train('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

------------------
 scrip file code `load deeb;
trdata=[deeb(1:8,2:6);deeb(11:18,2:6)];
gr=[deeb(1:8,1);deeb(11:18,1)];
testdata=[deeb(9:10,2:6);deeb(19:20,2:6)];
svmstr=svmtrain(trdata,gr);
result = svmclassify(svmstr,testdata);
output = result;`
----------------------------
the pushbutton2_Callback code is :

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
classifyDeeb.m
```

---

the script file, the figure  and  the matrix data ( deeb.mat) file are in the same folder.
please help 
thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
You can use `run()` on the m-file name.  You can even include the full path to the script if it is in another directory.

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
run('classifyDeeb.m')
```

or call it without the extension.  This will work as long as it is located in on of the Matlab's Paths.

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
classifyDeeb
```

Comment: i try with the two options: no error , but script file is not run, i can run it from command window

Comment: Are you sure it isn't running?  Add a line at the very beginning of classifyDeeb.m with something like `disp('I am running')`  and see if it prints to the command line.  I suspect it is running but you have some other kind issue.

Comment: Also is case you are not aware.  If you are running a script withing a GUI like this it will not see variables from your default workspace.  It will be run within the scope of the pushbutton function.  So if the script relies on variables in your workspace it wont work.

Comment: its running and display ( i am running) but not run the real code , as you said the scripts relies on variables in  the work space. i have a  variable as matrix file ( which is deeb.mat ). what to do to get it run? thank you for your help

Comment: Include the matrix as a field of `handles`, and send it as an input to the script (that should become to be a function)